# Remove remote file using sftp and private key (Solaris)

Tags: solaris, sftp

I have a Solaris server and I need to remove a file at remote machine using sftp (I can't use ssh).
Is it possible to pass a private key for auth to this command (I don't see -i parameter in Solaris) and how to remove this file?
Thanks.

Comment: SFTP runs over SSH. Why can't you use SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the -o option to pass SSH options. Eg

```
sftp -oIdentityFile=/path/to/identity user@host
```

This will connect and start the interactive SFTP session. Enter the commands following the `sftp>` prompt:

```
sftp> rm /path/to/file
Removing /path/to/file
sftp> bye
```

And you're done!